# placing images based on co-ordinate values randomly in android

Tags: android

I want to place images randomly based on the (x,y) co-ordinate values and that should compatible with all the devices having any screen resolution.

Give a clear description of co-ordinate system for any device screens.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a random number between
`0 to (screen width - image width)` for `x`,
and a random number between
`0 to (screen height - image height)` for `y`.

And set them as the x and y coordinates of your image. I don't feel any more explanation is necessary.

BTW, the coordinate system for mobile device is as follows.

- Origin is at top left corner.
- Value of x coordinate increases to the right
- And that of y coordinate increases to  the bottom.